# Codepen like template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, layout

I'm building a web application with AngularJS.

The application should behave like Codepen:

- 4 sections,
- allowing the user to hide/show one section or another
- with a resizing element allowing the user to shrink or enlarge sections.

I snooped on Codepen's code and I realized it's intensively relying on JQuery-UI.

I'd like to find any Codepen-like boilerplate template or similar example using Twitter Bootstrap or matching AngularJS
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found these solutions:

1. [UI-Layout](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-layout)
2. [Flexy Layout](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/flexy-layout/src/index.html#started) (discontinued?)
3. [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253161/2929757) (CSS based)

Answer (score 1):

Plunker (http://www.plnkr.co) which is similar to CodePen is created using Angular. 
Check out the GitHub Repo: https://github.com/filearts/plunker