# Resizable Angular side bar

Tags: angular, sidebar, resizable, angular7

Is there an example in Angular 7 with a side bar that may be resized by the user? An example on Stackblitz would be ideal.

I have tried ng-sidebar and material's sidenav, but I could not find out, how to make these sidebars resizable.

Comment: What do you mean by resizable? Collapsible?

Comment: material table have resizable side nav

Comment: Here's an example of how I did achieved the desired result, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378233/7313203