# Angular : create movable vertical line

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to divide page into two parts with vertical line (some thing like slider and able to scroll horizontally across page). I have to perform some functions only on one side. I don't know how to do this. Could you please give me some ideas to do this?

[image]

**Edited:**
Should be something like this

[image]

Comment: It's not Angular job, to draw pages... :-) It's your view job...

Comment: @MarcoS Yes, I agreed. But How can I do this? :-)

Comment: See Claudio Alves answer...

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like [bg-splitter](http://blackgate.github.io/bg-splitter/)

or [Angular JS resizable div directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368485/angular-js-resizable-div-directive)

Comment: No I don't want to split the <div>. I just wanted to do apply functions  only on one of the same <div>

Answer (score 1):

Try this jsFiddle I just created -> https://jsfiddle.net/larsjueljens/tLq2t04a/8/

This is basically three divs:

```
<div class="left">
  This is the left content
</div>
<div class="divider">
</div>
<div class="right">
  This is the right content
</div>
```

Initial style:

```
.left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px:
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.divider {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 220px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
var isMouseDown = false, 
        leftContent = document.querySelector('.left'),
        divider = document.querySelector('.divider'),
    rightContent = document.querySelector('.right');

divider.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    isMouseDown = true;
});

divider.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    isMouseDown = false;
});

divider.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
    leftContent.style.width = (event.clientX - 10) + 'px';
    divider.style.left = (event.clientX - 10) + 'px';
    rightContent.style.left = (event.clientX + 10) + 'px';
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually you are splitting <div> into 3 sub elements i.e., 3 <div>'s, I don't want to split the <div> :-(

Comment: No, I think it is more like splitting the <body> into 3 sub elements (<div>).

Answer (score 0):

Bro, whatever you are asking has nothing to do with angular. This will be done by css property of overflow-y:auto;

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #div1{width:600px;background:yellow;height:60px;}
    #div2{width:60%;background:green;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:none;height:60px;}
    #div3{width:40%;background:pink;}
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
    <script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

        //code here
    });
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: and how this code enables **horisontal** resize and drag ability?

Comment: I should be able to move vertical line towards left/right. :-)